# Reading multiple files using pyspark with same columns but different ordering

Tags: python, dataframe, scala, pyspark, pyspark-schema

Suppose I have two files.

file0.txt

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |

file1.txt

| field2 | field1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

Now, if I write:

```
spark.read.csv(["./file0.txt""./file1.txt"], sep=',', header=True, inferSchema=True).show()
```

the following dataframe is read by spark.

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

but it should have been,

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |

I tried using inferSchema. As I have a lot of files in the folder I cannot hardcode the ordering of the columns in the csvs.

Comment: you could read one file at a time and then append them using `unionByName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read them one at a time and then union them, so something like this,

```
import glob

path = 'test_data/'

files=glob.glob(path +'*.txt')

for idx,f in enumerate(files):
    if idx == 0:
        df = spark.read.csv(f, sep=',', header=True, inferSchema=True)
        final_df = df
    else:
        df = spark.read.csv(f, sep=',', header=True, inferSchema=True)
        final_df=final_df.unionByName(df)
```

output:

```
+------+------+
|field1|field2|
+------+------+
|     1|     2|
|     1|     2|
|     1|     2|
|     1|     2|
+------+------+
```